# Hook directory not found

Tags: python, hook, pyinstaller, matplotlib-basemap

I try to create a `.exe` with Pyinstaller. I need to include a hook called `hook-mpl_toolkits.basemap`. I added the hook in the `.spec`file as follow:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['xxx.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\...\\...\\xxx'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['C:\\...\\...\\hooks\\hook-mpl_toolkits.basemap.py'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='map',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='map')
```

But when I run "`Pyinstaller xxx.spec`", I receive an error:

> Hook directory not found

Ann Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hookspath` is a path, not a file.  It will need to be:

```
hookspath=['C:\\...\\...\\hooks'],
```

The hooks themselves are chosen to match the name of the python module, so this case:

```
mpl_toolkits.basemap
```